# Partial pattern matching for elements that are in two lists in TCL

Tags: pattern-matching, tcl

So, lets say I have these two lists as below:

`ListA` contains:

```
{{feed_sesmmu1_qmusharemem_se_smmu0_int}
{feed_sesmmu1_qmusharemem_se_smmu0_soc_rd_datvld}
{feed_sesmmu1_qmusharemem_se_smmu0_soc_rd_dat[31]}
{feed_sesmmu1_qmusharemem_se_smmu0_soc_rd_dat[30]} 
{feed_sesmmu1_qmusharemem_se_smmu0_soc_rd_dat[29]}
{feed_sesmmu1_qmusharemem_se_smmu0_soc_rd_dat[28]}
{feed_sesmmu1_qmusharemem_se_smmu0_soc_rd_dat[27]}
{feed_sesmmu1_qmusharemem_se_smmu0_soc_rd_dat[26]}}
```

and `ListB`:

```
{{se_smmu0_int}
{se_smmu0_soc_rd_datvld}
{se_smmu0_soc_rd_dat[29]}
{se_smmu0_soc_rd_dat[31]}
{se_smmu0_soc_rd_dat[30]}
{se_smmu0_soc_rd_dat[28]} 
{se_smmu0_soc_rd_dat[26]}
{se_smmu0_soc_rd_dat[27]}}
```

Now I need `{feed_sesmmu1_qmusharemem_se_smmu0_soc_rd_dat[27]}` to match `{se_smmu0_soc_rd_dat[27]}` and other elements of `listA` should match their counterparts in `listB`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with

```
lmap s $ListB {
    lsearch -inline $listA *[string map {[ \\[ ] \\]} $s]
}
```

The idea is to take each item in the list `ListB` and search for that item in the list `listA`. There are to caveats: some of the items in `ListB` have brackets (`[` `]`) in them, and those characters are special to the glob search that `lsearch` uses by default. So we will escape them: `string map {[ \\[ ] \\]} $s`. Also, the item from `ListB` is going to be a suffix in `listA`, so we need to prepend a star, `*` for "any character".

If you don't have `lmap` and don't want to use the drop-in replacement in the [lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570) link:

```
set result {}
foreach s $ListB {
    lappend result [lsearch -inline $listA *[string map {[ \\[ ] \\]} $s]]
}
puts $result
```

Documentation:
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

*Syntax of Tcl string matching:*

- `*` matches a sequence of zero or more characters
- `?` matches a single character
- `[chars]` matches a single character in the set given by *chars* (^ does *not* negate; a range can be given as *a-z*)
- `\x` matches the character *x*, even if that character is special (one of `*?[]\`)

Comment: Can we do the same thing in another way without having to use lmap.. For some reason my tcl shell says that lmap is an invalid command..

Comment: Since you are using an older Tcl version, you can use `foreach {s} $ListB { ...}` and process each result as needed.   Recommend upgrading Tcl if possible.

Comment: @AvasRoy: look at the documentation links. At the first link you'll find a short snippet of code that adds lmap so you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with explicit `foreach` loops, in case `lmap` is not available. It also avoids glob-style string matching if favor of a range-based match:

```
proc endsWidth {s suffix} {
    set index end-[expr {[string length $suffix]-1}]
    return [expr {[string range $s $index end] eq $suffix}]
}

foreach b $listB {
    foreach a $listA {
        if {[endsWidth $a $b]} {
            puts "$a $b"
        }
    }
}
```